# I2C bus arbitration - communication layer

Tags: i2c, digital-communications, bus

I want to understand about the communication layer on which I2C Bus arbitration is done.
My question is based on [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/448349/bus-mastering-vs-bus-arbitration) question which was previously asked here.

The accepted answer states that

> Bus arbitration is not part of several of the protocols you mention.
>   RS422, RS485 and SPI can have bus arbitration but it is not part of
>   the protocol, rather must be implemented on a different communications
>   layer.

I understand the I2C arbitration procedure but I want to understand that on which communication layer is I2C bus arbitration done ?

Can someone brief on the communication layer regarding the bus arbitration for I2C protocol and other protocols which have bus arbitration

Comment: I2C is so simple that it doesn't really have layers to speak of. You can download the whole spec from NXP and read it in an hour or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I2C arbitration works at the datalink level. I2C uses open-drain connections: SDA is low if any device pulls it low, but SDA is high only when all devices are not pulling it low. So during I2C slave address where two masters are transmitting, if one master pulls SDA low while the other master wants SDA high, then the open-drain datalink resolves the conflict in favor of the low value. Whichever master is transmitting the higher-numbered slave address, lost the I2C arbitration and must immediately release the bus. This only works if both I2C masters detect during each bit transfer that SDA is in the requested state. Not all I2C implementations are compatible with multi-master systems. A software bit-banging I2C master might not support multi-master address arbitration.