# Understanding OSI Communication Model in Hardware

Tags: communication, digital-communications, telecommunications

I have gone through the OSI communication model and the associated levels.

But I do not understand on how is this implemented in the Hardware level. Or let me put it like this.

Suppose we have a USB (2.0 and 3.0) communication device from my Host PC to a Device connected. Like, from the hardware perspective, I can understand and try to design the circuit connection between the host and the device. This is just the physical layer, right?

How to understand the datalink, network and the higher layers from a hardware perspective?
Like, does each data bit or say packet of bits get filtered by the host controller during its processing stage? I know the previous line does not make sense. That's where I am stuck.

If someones says, (for example, take I2C communication) that something is taken care at the datalink layer, what does the datalink layer actually do when they say this or what do they mean?

**Simply put : What happens in the electronics level or the IC level during each stage of the OSI Communication level.**

How does a Hardware Engineer understands this?
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

> How does a Hardware Engineer understands this? Please help.

You don't, it's all software* from there. The whole point of this layering is to hide information about what's in the other layers. Then you only have to think about the layer you're in.

You provide services to the layer immediately above you.

You use services provided by the layer immediately below you.

*In some devices, the 'software' might be accelerated by dedicated hardware, but it's still best to think of it as a process best described by decisions being made on data

Comment: I remember asking a question in this forum long back regarding an I2C Communication. I received an answer mentioning something about the datalink layer. Back then, My query was solved. But recently I gave a read of the OSI and this struck me.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/468159/i2c-bus-arbitration-communication-layer

Comment: Please Check the above question and the accepted answer. It mentions about datalink layer

Comment: @Newbie I thought you were asking 'What happens in the electronics level or the IC level during each stage of the OSI Communication level.' What you see in the other question is correct that the I2C datalink layer contains an arbitration mechanism that relies on specific aspects of the I2C hardware. As such it's not really following the layering model well at that level. You're trying to compare chalk with cheese, or maybe oranges, if you want to assume all layered models have the same components, or services, or strict boundaries between layers.

Comment: @Newbie What happens on a hardware level should be exactly how you expect the IC to behave. It's not like hardware has the capability of knowing its intended use but it is built to support whatever solution you try to configure it to be. I agree with Neil here. This seems more software related than hardware surrounded by TCP/IP and OSI protocols. You can design hardware to make sure you have proper data flow. Something like I2C isn't a good application of what you're asking for because that's more of an onboard, dedicated topology whereas OSI can go on for a long distance.

Comment: As noted, some of the protocol layers are often implemented in hardware (which makes *software* debugging almost impossible) either by dedicated hardware (generally true of PCI express and Infiniband to define the link training state machines) or (quite often) an instantiated controller with firmware (the 8051 is a popular choice and many USB controllers take this approach). Flexibility is provided in some cases by providing registers to set up various parameters.

Comment: @Neil_UK , I am trying to understand but not able to get complete clarity. Can you please explain a little more just the comment you explained regarding the I2C and data link layer. What does data link layer corresponds in Electrical terms

Comment: @Newbie The data link layer is not 'electrical', it is a protocol, [see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer). In some systems, it's entirely in hardware, in other systems it's firmware or even software, often depending on the complexity of the physical layer. When you focus in on one particular system, you'll then see how that data link implementation is specified to work.